# how to create thymeleaf for-loop that deal the zero counter?

Tags: java, for-loop, thymeleaf

java for loop

```
int counter=10;
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++}{
  System.out.print(i);
}
```

thymleaf for loop

```
th:each="i:*{#numbers.sequence( 1, counter)}"
```

if counter=10, they all give 1,2,3...8,9,10
if counter=0; java loop will not print anything, but thymeleaf loop result as: 1,0.

How to create a for loop like java one in thymeleaf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are  seeing 1,0 is that it is counting backwards. for example

```
${#numbers.sequence(7,5)}
```

will result in `7, 6, 5`
i.e. `${#numbers.sequence(1,0)}` is equal to `${#numbers.sequence(1,0,-1)}`

---

**Edit:**

`${#numbers.sequence(1,0,1)}` seems to throw an error in the implementation against to what I originally thought. New  suggestion use something like

```
<th:block th:unless="${counter<1}" th:each="num: ${#numbers.sequence(1,counter)}">
<!-- Your loop body goes here -->
</th:block>
```

---

**Edit 2(13-07-2017):**

A behaviour change was requested and thereby implemented by the Thymeleaf team for this
So from ***3.0.7-SNAPSHOT*** onwards so we can directly use the below to return an empty sequence instead an error. [Issue Link](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/621)

```
${#numbers.sequence(1,0,1)}
```

Comment: if counter =0, ${#numbers.sequence(1,0,1)} will give you a error

Comment: Hi @Dark, I knew there are some workaround, but I want a simple loop. I am working on a demo project, if Thymeleaf cannot obtain the target, we may not migrate to or use it for real project. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: Ok. But I don't know why you term it as a workaround. That piece of code does exactly what you intended to do.

Comment: You won't write code as if(counter>1){
    for(int i=1;i<counter;i++){
        ///
    }}. @Dark

Comment: The thymeleaf owner accepted my suggestion, already in 3.0.7-SNAPSHOT,  Can you add the link the link to your answer ,let 
 others easy to see. https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/621#issuecomment-314898727

Comment: @shuan Thanks for letting me know. I updated the post.